Effect size of categorical variables
If I have bio test of two categories with different dimensions and larger size=190 samples , df=63 . Is cramer V suitable in this case? And how would be the interpretation considering the effect size? Is lambda, contingency coefficient calculated by SPSS are valid also?

The appropriateness and the interpretation of the effect size depends on the research question you're trying to answer, so you should provide more details to get a good answer. What is it that you want to learn from your data, ultimately? Can you provide more information about it? (e.g. Is any of the two variables binary? Ordinal? How have they been measured? Is one of the variables originally a continuous variable that has been binned?, etc.) Sharing a very small snippet of the data might be useful. You can edit your question with the "edit" link just under the question.
